# How to fix curl: (35) SSL certificate problem: Couldn't understand the server certificate format?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried to install chromedriver using homebrew and got the following error.

> $ sudo brew install chromedriver
>   ==> Using the sandbox
>   ==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_ma
>
> curl: (35) SSL certificate problem: Couldn't understand the server certificate format
>   Error: Failed to download resource "chromedriver"
>   Download failed: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_mac64.zip

I updated the curl to version 7.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0) using homebrew and link it but no luck.

My os is OSX 10.11.5 and curl -V result is following :

> $ /usr/bin/curl -V
>   curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a regression for root brew: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/796

Comment: Is it still happening?

Comment: No, I updated brew and problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Your `curl` is using `SecureTransport` which is using macOS builtin version of SSL which likely be incapable of outgoing encrypted web communications, instead of OpenSSL.

So try reinstalling `curl` via Homebrew with the following options to support OpenSSL:

```
brew reinstall curl --with-libssh2 --with-openssl
```

<sup>Note: Paste above line into the Terminal.</sup>

Related: [cURL fails with error: Couldn't understand the server certificate format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38707493/55075).

Answer (score 2):

Open [chromedriver_mac64.zip](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_mac64.zip) in your browser. If you see this message:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>
    We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location
  </Details>
</Error>
```

Then Google is restricting your access. Simply download that file with an alternative network/IP/location. Then move the file to `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/` or `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/` due to the installation of Homebrew. Then try to reinstall. Homebrew will use downloaded file.

Alternatively you can use a network proxy in the terminal while running `brew` command.